# Pandas: Group By Having / Filtering Troubles

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which looks like this:

```
| Index   | Item       | Value       |
+---------+------------+-------------+
|  0      | 1024       | 20          |
|  1      | 1024       | 27          |
|  2      | 1024       | 19          |
|  3      | 4096       | 44          |
| ...     | ...        | ...         |
```

Now i can groupby this dataframe by the Item column and perform some aggregations on the value:

```
grouped = df.groupby(df['Item']).agg({'Value':['median', 'mean', 'std', 'count']})
```

If I now look into that grouped object, it looks like a stacked dataframe:

```
grouped.head()

|        | Value                       |
+--------+-----------------------------+
|        | median | mean | std | count |
+--------+--------+------+-----+-------+
| Item   |        |      |     |       |
+--------+--------+------+-----+-------+
| 1024   |  20    | 22.0 | 4.3 | 3     |
| 4096   |  44    | 44.0 | NaN | 1     |
+--------+--------+------+-----+-------+
```

I now would like to only filter the grouped items which for example have a count > 1, so I tried the following:

```
filtered = grouped.filter(lambda x: x['count'] > 1)
```

But I get a: TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

I also tried

```
filtered = grouped.filter(lambda x: x.Value.count > 1)
```

or

```
filtered = grouped[grouped.Age.count > 1]
```

but the last one only throws KeyError: True

How can I achieve this filtering in that case, in SQL it would be like writing a `GROUP BY` / `HAVING` clause, when I want to filter the aggregated grouped table in pandas?

How could I for example write a query that only returns the rows where median == mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
grouped[grouped.Value['count'] > 1]
```

will do it. Obviously, the name count has two meanings on that object, so it is better to refer to it using the syntax above.

Answer (score 1):

The pandas way for your question about "median == mean" is

```
df.groupby(df['Item']).filter(lambda x: x['Value'].median() == x['Value'].mean())

# One call to median(), one to mean()
```

Comment: @Regenschein thank you for correcting - copy-paste :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use easier solution - remove `Multiindex` from columns adding `['Value']` before `agg` and then use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
g1 = (df.groupby(df['Item'])['Value'].agg(['median', 'mean', 'std', 'count']))
print (g1)

      median  mean       std  count
Item                               
1024      20    22  4.358899      3
4096      44    44       NaN      1

filtered = g1[g1['count'] > 1]
print (filtered)
      median  mean       std  count
Item                               
1024      20    22  4.358899      3
```